# Why is ListPopupWindow OnItemClickListener not called?

Tags: android, popup

For some reason I can't get this popup to react to clicks, onItemClick is not called.

```
String[] actions = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.layout_popup_list_item, actions);
        popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());
        popupWindow.setAnchorView(btnConferenceActions);
        popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
        popupWindow.setWidth(measureContentWidth(adapter));
        popupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.END);
        popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                hideConferenceActionsList();
                switch (position){
                   case 0:
                       Log.i("TAG", "Item 0");
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       Log.i("TAG", "Item 1");
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       Log.i("TAG", "Item 2");
                       break;
            }
        });
        popupWindow.show();
```

This popup is shown inside custom view, and it shows fine except it's not reating to clicks

Answer (score 0):

if you move `popupWindow.show();` up a couple lines into the `setOnItemClickListener()` method, does that correct it?

```
String[] actions = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.layout_popup_list_item, actions);
    popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());
    popupWindow.setAnchorView(btnConferenceActions);
    popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
    popupWindow.setWidth(measureContentWidth(adapter));
    popupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.END);
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            hideConferenceActionsList();
            switch (position){
               case 0:
                   Log.i("TAG", "Item 0");
                   break;
               case 1:
                   Log.i("TAG", "Item 1");
                   break;
               case 2:
                   Log.i("TAG", "Item 2");
                   break;
            popupWindow.show();     /* If it is placed here */
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean to put it before setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: No. Inside the method.

Comment: But what's the point, popup won't show without show()

Comment: If you have the .show() placed where I have it above?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved by modifying my popup list item layout as follows.

Before(Not working):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/Text.Regular"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:paddingStart="10dp"
  android:paddingEnd="10dp"
  android:paddingTop="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="16dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

/>

After:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/Text.Regular"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:paddingStart="10dp"
  android:paddingEnd="10dp"
  android:paddingTop="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="16dp"
```

/>